# Searching for the most comfortable and cost efficient tool to implement Test Automation for Multiple Environments (Desktop, WEB and Mobile)

Tags: automated-testing, mobile, windows, ranorex, mobile-automation

Planning to automate testing for Multiple Environments (Desktop, WEB and Mobile). 
Searching for the most comfortable and cost efficient tool to use. Found some tools: [Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com/), [eggPlant](http://www.testplant.com/eggplant/testing-tools/), TestComplete and T-Plan Robot.
Can anybody suggest me any tool I missed or give me advice, what tool is better from the listed ones above? :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Telerik's Test Studio** is also a good tool and will provide you required support and features. You can use this tool for testing Web, Mobile, Desktop (but only WPF) applications. test Complete is also a good tool which will suffice your requirements (advantage is it supports more variety of Desktop applications).

Again, cost wise Test Studio is cheaper than Test Complete and it offers Performance + Load test features too in same license. You may need to consider the Performance testing feature too when selecting tool, as NFRs also vital part of delivery quality *(sometimes it got completely neglected)*.

You can also go for free tools but then you need to use multiple tools for the same like Selenium (web), Selendroid (android) and Robot (desktop).

So, if you can go for paid tools (depending upon project budget and ROI) then Test Complete and/or Test Studio are good tools. Start with evaluation of these tools and create POC using Trial versions, then create a **Short Summary** *(if you require for your own analysis only)* or **Descriptive Analysis** *(if you need to provide it to management/client for license procurement)* to decide which too is good for you.

Use some technique for analysis like:-

**1. Rating method**

**2. Decision tree analysis, etc.**

this will provide you a clear picture which tool you should go for (based on features, requirements, support, cost and others) and can show your **Decision Analysis Report** and **POC** to customer/ project members to support your decision.

Comment: +1 for Telerik. If you have a desktop application, like the old winforms, the only reliable tool I have used was AutoIt.

Answer (score 0):

Personally for me and the company we like using selenium and using [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/). To be honest it's the best multiple platform tool I have used, so its worth taking a look at.

Comment: But Sauce Labs is only for WEB and Mobile apps testing. I need tool that would be suitable for Desktop, Web and Mobile testing :) Or what did you mean? :)

Comment: Sauce Labs indeed does testing for desktop applications! take a look at their documentation, I have tested a lot of desktop applications with their services.